# Solution for adding extra column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have one user table and want to maintain a flag for externalRequester and externalReviewer. But per 1000 users only 80 to 100 users are external Requester or reviewer.
Is that right way to add column in user table to maintain flag?
What about the remaining empty values ?
Please suggest any solution for it.

Comment: I can add one column for it. But what about the empty spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. How many of these sorts of flags are you going to add? And what will you do with them?

Space is not likely to be an issue unless you have *a lot* of these flag columns. A `tinyint` for a simple yes/no flag or an [`enum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) for several choices is also only 1 or 2 bytes per row.

If there are many such flags (`is_reviewer`, `is_admin`, `is_user`) maintaining indexes for all of them, and their combinations, might be troublesome, and will eat up more disk space.

---

An alternative is to have separate tables for each type. This is particularly useful when representing a special type of a thing.

```
create table reviewers (
    id serial primary key,
    user_id bigint not null,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
        on delete cascade
);
```

Then find your reviewers with a [left join](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/%2fArticles%2f33052%2fVisual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

```
select users.*
from reviewers
left join users on users.id = reviewers.id;
```

This might seem overkill, but its useful if you need to add more information to only users who are reviewers. You'd add columns to `reviewers` rather than `users` which can avoid wasting a lot of space. For example, you might want to store when a user was made a reviewer by adding `reviewers.created_at`.

It also neatly handles indexing. MySQL uses one index per table in the query, so searching for users who are reviewers is always on an index.

This can also help with referential integrity. For example, `reviews` should only be by users who are reviewers. With a flag, `reviews` references `users` and it can potentially reference any `user`. This invites bugs and extra complexity to keep your data integrity.

With a `reviewers` table, `reviews` references `reviewers` guaranteeing integrity.

```
create table reviews (
    id serial primary key,
    reviewer_id bigint not null,
    foreign key (reviewer_id) references reviewers(id)
        on delete cascade,
    review text not null,
    stars tinyint not null
);
```